# NestJs load environment variables on npm start

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, nodemon, nestjs

There`s a more **easy** way to load your env vars using .env files.

Just add `--require dotenv/config` to your start script, like: `node --require dotenv/config server.js`.
https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv

But, the problem is that this does not seems to work with nodemon and I can`t figure out how to do it.
I tried:

```
 "start:dev": "nodemon --require dotenv/config",
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 4):

According to this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/878), nodemon does not accept cli parameters for node. However, you can use this workaround to pass params:

```
nodemon --exec "node -r dotenv/config" index.js
```

You can put this in your npm start command by editing the `package.json`:

```
"start": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register -r dotenv/config src/main.ts",
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you want to use it in the `start:dev` command, edit the `nodemon.json` file:

```
"exec": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register -r dotenv/config src/main.ts"
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: @AndreBaltieri I've added the necessary file edits. :-)

Answer (score 0):

if someone has reached here looking for a generic answer of how to set environment variables in nestjs then you got to read this official docs [Nestjs Configuration](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration)